# Как попасть в дочерний элемент js?

Tags: javascript

Есть код на html.

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="in">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <p id="plus">+</p>
        <p id="def">def</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

И на js:

```js
el = document.getElementById("main");
el = el.getElementsByClassName("in")[0];
```

Таким образом, после исполнения кода `el` равен всему тегу `div`. Как в el записать
 `<p id="plus">+</p>`?

Про document.getElementById я знаю, но хотелось бы именно таким путём.

```
﻿
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каким "таким" путем? Значение `id` должно быть уникально на странице.

```
el = document.getElementById("plus");
```

Делайте:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="in">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <p class="plus">+</p>
        <p class="def">def</p>
    </div>
</div>

el = document.querySelectorAll("#main .in .plus")[0];
```

Comment: Именно, "сверху", то есть сначала получить main, в нём найти класс "in", взять 0 элемент и в нём найти p с id="plus". То есть по сути, весь вопрос заключается в том, как попасть во дочерний элемент объекта только по id

Comment: @igor_bal Уникальность `id` состоит в том, что его "дочерность" вообще роли не играет.